# asp.net mvc Controller.RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName);
```

means I cannot do

```
public static ActionResult RedirectToErrorAction(this Controller controller)
{
    // redirect to custom error page
    return controller.RedirectToAction("error", "support");
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: any idea to a workaround

Comment: From what youre saying your action name is "error" and it lies in your controller that is named supportcontroller, but why are you naming a controller action an mvc method name

Comment: RedirectToErrorAction is an extension method added to Controller so I may use it across many controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider returning a custom, shared error view instead, but if you really need to do this, you might want to consider using reflection to invoke the internal method.  The former could be implemented in a base controller that becomes the foundation for all your controllers.

First example:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{ 
    private ActionResult CreateErrorResult( string message )
    {
         ViewData["message"] = message;
         ...
         return new View( "CustomError" );
    }
}
```

Second example (if getting the internal attribute via reflection works):

```
public static ActionResult RedirectToErrorAction(this Controller controller)
{
    MethodInfo info = typeof(Controller).GetMethod( "RedirectToAction",
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance,
                            null,
                            new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) },
                            null );
    return info.Invoke( controller, new object[] { "error", "support" } )
               as ActionResult;
}
```

Comment: GetMethod will not work on protected methods and the Invoke needs to be cast to ActionResult.

Comment: Sorry -- you might be able to get it using BindingFlags.NonPublic.